Esri.ArcGISRuntime does not compatible with .net 8.0 - EXE type
I am using Esri.ArcGISRuntime to get coordinates by providing location name. It is integrated to the Azure function and Azure function is implemented using .NET8.0 and it is EXE type project. I can't change the out put type from EXE to class library. Because of the changes in .NET framework. Therefore, changing the output type to "Class Library" is not an option.
When I add the Esri.ArcGISRuntime nuget package into my project I get below error during the compile time.
"The 'Esri.ArcGISRuntime' nuget package cannot be used to target 'net8.0' for output type 'Exe'. Only platform-agnostic class libraries or Windows, iOS and Android platforms are supported"
Is there any other possibility integrate this library without changing the output type.
P.S - Downgrading the framework is also not an option.

No you must build the executable with a platform moniker.
Also pretty sure using the Sdk in a server scenario is against the terms of use of the library.

Thanks for the information.
